# Regular expression that allow only divisible by three

Tags: regex

My regular expression is following:

```
^([0369]|[258][0369]*[147]|[147]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*[258]|[258][0369]*[258]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*[258]|[147]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*[147][0369]*[147]|[258][0369]*[258]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*[147][0369]*[147])*$
```

This allow us too divisible by 3  numbers but it also allowing me to 0 which is not require me please help me out it restrict me to insert 0 and allow me 1. so finally my requirement is it allow us all multi-player of 3 and we can also enter value 1 .

Comment: What made you think regex was the tool for this job?!

Comment: Your request doesn't make any sense. 0 is divisible by 3, and 1 is not divisible by 3.

Comment: Related: [This answer, also dealing with inappropriate uses of regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1863564)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regex is **not** what you want here. While possible, it is definitely not the tool you want to be using for a task like that.

Instead, translate this in whatever language you are using

> See other answer, my code was wrong!

Should be simple enough, and I am pretty sure `%` is available in almost ALL languages.

Comment: Why the extra check for `input == 1`? It'll be covered by the first case itself.

Comment: `1 % 3 == 1` which is greater than zero, so the first condition itself will be `true` and the function returns. Second condition is redundant and never executes.

Comment: `return (input % 3) == 0 || input == 1;` will return `true` for all multiples of 3, and 1.

Comment: @CinCout --- Sorry, it's still early in the morning. Don't do bools in the morning, kids. Deleted my comment. --- I rechecked the post (it is quite old) and my answer is obviously false. Feel free to edit it as you wish.

Comment: Your code is accepting all non-multiples of 3 instead. Added a separate correct answer.

Comment: @CinCout Yeah, I noticed that now. No idea why OP hasn't picked up on that. -- I think editing the answer would be better because it's unlikely OP will change the accepted answer after such a long time...

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need to accept any number that is a multiple of 3, along with the exception of 1.

As suggested by [@Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204693) regex is not the tool of choice here. But his answer is accepting all non-multiples of 3, which is incorrect.

The following simple function will do:

```
bool isValid(int input)
{
    return ((0 == (input % 3)) || (1 == input));
}
```